# NavigationView behavior changes with background color in content view

Tags: swiftui

I try to show a scrollview with a non-white background color. However no matter what I do, as soon as I set a background color the navigation bar starts acting up. The items of my scroll view no longer scroll under it, and the bar does not collapse either. The white background seems to become translucent and everything shows through.

Any idea?

```
struct ExpoListView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue
                ScrollView {
                    Text("XXX")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("XXX")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("XXX")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("XXX")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("XXX")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("expo")
        }
    }
}
```

And then using the scroll view leads to:
[image]

Removing `Color.blue` and using the scroll gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider this one

[image: demo]

```
struct ExpoListView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { gp in
                ScrollView {
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)
                        VStack {
                            Text("XXX")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("XXX")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("XXX")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("XXX")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("XXX")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }.frame(minHeight: gp.size.height)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("expo")
            }
        }
    }
}
```